# Python list scope outside a function

Tags: python, list, function

I am having a problem which is hard to explain because there's a lot of code involve. So it boils down to the following problem.

I am trying to access the list **xxx** outside the function **foo** but I am getting unexpected results. Can someone please explain why?

Here's my function which I have created to show the problem:

```
def foo(xxx = []):
    if len(xxx) == 5:
        return xxx
    xxx += [1]
    foo()
    return xxx
```

If I run

```
print foo()
```

I get

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which is what I expect.

But I want the list **xxx** to be accessible outside foo. So, I am doing

```
xxx = []
print foo(xxx)
print xxx
```

Now I expect to get the list **xxx** to be

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

but what I am getting **xxx** to be, is

```
[1]
```

which is not what I expect.

Can someone explain why? And is it possible to access the correct **xxx** outside **foo** without accessing it through the output of the function **foo**? The reason I want to do this is because in my actual code I am returning something other than in my function **foo** and making changes to **xxx** which I want to see after the **foo** has executed. I can make the function also return **xxx** every time but this will make my code unnecessarily bulky. But I am not sure if I am compromising the code quality. I don't know. Please suggest which ever way is the best.

Thanks

Comment: Passing in an argument replaces the default argument. So it will happily modify a different `list` when provided (and that `list` will be modified even if not returned), otherwise it's modifying the shared `list` used as a default (which cannot be accessed normally without returning it).

Comment: Just a side note (that has nothing to do with your question): try to avoid mutable default arguments. Their behavior is counter intuitive and people using your code may get unexpected results.

Comment: I am myself very confused with this code. What's the substitute for mutable default arguments?

Comment: It depends: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I found my answer. By using the code by @Hammerite I am getting the desired functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xxx = []
print foo(xxx)
print xxx
```

In this code you are calling `foo()` with the list you created outside the function, called `xxx`. But within the function, you are recursing to call `foo()` without parameters, so it modifies the list that was created at function definition time by the expression for the default argument value. (Importantly, this is the same list every time you call the function without supplying a value for that argument.)

Compare what happens when you define `foo` like this instead:

```
def foo(xxx = None):
    if xxx is None:
        xxx = []
    if len(xxx) == 5:
        return xxx
    xxx += [1]
    foo()
    return xxx
```

... and what happens when you define it like this:

```
def foo(xxx = None):
    if xxx is None:
        xxx = []
    if len(xxx) == 5:
        return xxx
    xxx += [1]
    foo(xxx)
    return xxx
```

Comment: The second code which you mentioned solved my problem. But trying understand the difference between all the three is spinning my mind.

Comment: Roughly speaking when you write foo(xxx=[]) the xxx value is initialized on the module level and would be shared between all calls to the function - not created every time you make a call. There is a lot of information about this on web and StackOverflow.